# Different artifacts when job succeeded and failed with GitLab CI

Tags: gitlab-ci

Need to upload artifact `binary.bin` when job succeeded and `build_trace.log` when failed.

Looking on [artifacts:when](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#artifactswhen)
I don't see such ability.

#### Is there some tricky hack?

I would like to see something like

```
job:
  artifacts:
    - name: failed_trace_log
      when: on_failure
      paths:
      - build_trace.log
    - name: succeed
      when: on_success
      paths:
      - binary.bin
```

Current workaround is:

```
job:
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
    - build_trace.log
    - binary.bin
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One alternative is to use [when:on_failure](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#when) in a cleanup job after the first.

```
stages:
  - build
  - cleanup_build

job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - make build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - binary.bin

cleanup_job:
  when: on_failure
  stage: cleanup_build
  script:
    - do cleanup
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build_trace.log
```

Comment: That does not work, because `cleanup_job` runs in a completely different environment than `job`, possibly on another machine, and thus cannot access `build_trace.log`.

Comment: Any news or solution since ?